# Is there a way to find the length of an array in MongoDB without returning the entire array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm paginating a list of embedded documents, and I'm wondering if there's a cheap way to find out the length of that list, analogous to count() for documents . I know that

```
array.length
```

works, but I'm guessing that's it's [slow and inefficient](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bcount%28%29%7D%7D).

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a dedicated counter of the array as part of the document. There is no other efficient way to determine the length of an array.